# Main.java:18: error: array required, but String found

Tags: string

Can anyone resolve this java code i have issues in type casting .

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=234;
        int ans=1;
        int diff;
        int sum=0;
        String s = Integer.toString(n);
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            ans=ans*Integer.parseInt(s[i]);//not converting pls help me
            sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(s[i]);//not type casting pls help me
        }
        diff=ans-sum;
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: As the answer by Jens shows, the issue is that you need to convert `String s` to a char array before you can index to a specific character in it.

Answer (score 1):

s is a `String` if you want a number out of the string, you have to convert it to a `char[]` then can you access a specific index

```
Integer.parseInt(s.toCharArray()[i])
```